# Broken "Top Network Post" link and title

Tags: bug, user-interface

I have an empty "Top Network Post" title showing up on Stack Overflow for Meta.SE.

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330385/can-someone-fix-the-broken-links-in-this-historically-locked-question/330386) should be the post, but I'm not sure why the link or the title of the question would be broken (other than the fact that it was migrated).

For reference, [here is the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/-2147482643/330386#330386). It's broken, so...

Here's an image:

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like it was just unlucky.

Comment: I find it curious that the link goes to a negative question number...

Comment: [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=2147482643) the ID number of the broken HNQ reveals [another recent issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329407/invalid-recent-display-name) on SE Meta of a similar nature.

Comment: @IronFlare Not a Hot Network Question... a Top Network Post link.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. The rest of my comment stands as written, though.

Answer (score 4):

Initially writing as a comment this became long, so here is my suggestion and reason of the error.

Yes, the link is broken.
Anyways though, experimenting with the link of the post, I found changing:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/-2147482643/330386#330386

to

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330386#330386

would solve the problem. You can check this image:

[image]

Actually, there is no text within the `<span>` to show up in the area. Maybe a SO developer can handle this.

Comment: Hopefully we'll get an official response.

Comment: stack *overflow*.

Comment: @MCCCS Maybe, stack *overfloes*

Comment: Stack Over-*oh-noes*