# My top post shows more votes when viewed from my meta profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, upvotes

I have an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50027691/9819031) which currently has 15 upvotes.

[image: My top voted answer on Stack Overflow]

But when viewed from my Meta Stack Overflow profile, it shows up with 16 votes.

[image: Top network posts]

Also the case on my network profile:

[image: Network profile]

Somewhat related: [Broken "Top Network Post" link and title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387233/9819031)

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Also see [Post score in the Top Network Posts borked somewhere](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/256398)